# How can I put data in snake case from MySQL database and put it into value field for each item in the list in ejs with express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I'm preparing a form to take some data in the database for a local business. I was able to dynamically get the data from my MySQL database and put it into the drop down list but I am not able to populate the value that goes with the option tag as the value that the item gets because it has space in it. I decided to use lodash for converting the data to snake case but I'm not able to get that to fall into the value field.

App.js code

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const db = require("./util/database");
const _ = require("lodash");

const app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  })
);

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server Started at port 3000");
});

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  db.execute("SELECT customerName FROM customers")
    .then(([rows, fieldData]) => {
      // console.log(_.snakeCase(rows[0].customerName));
      const map = rows.map(name => _.snakeCase(name.customerName));
      res.render("home.ejs", {
        customerName: rows,
        customerNameSnakeCase: map
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});

app.post("/", function(req, res) {
  const quantity = req.body.quantity;
  const rate = req.body.rate;
  const amount = quantity * rate;

  res.render("another", {
    amountValue: amount
  });
});
```

home.ejs code

```
<%- include("partials/header"); -%>
</head>

<body>

    <form class="form-control" action="/" method="post">
        <input type="date" name="date">
        <label for="salePurchase">Type of Transaction</label>
        <select required>
            <option value="sale">Sale</option>
            <option value="purchase">Purchase</option>
            <option value="other">Others</option>
            <option value="payment">Payment</option>
            <option value="receipt">Receipts</option>
        </select>
        <label for="vehicleNumber">Vehicle Number</label>
        <input type="number" , name="vehicleNumber">
        <label for="partyName">Party Name</label>

        <select>
            <% customerName.forEach((name) => { %>
            <option value=""><%= name.customerName %></option>
            <% }) %>
        </select>

        <select>

        </select>
        <label for="factory">Factory</label>
        <select>
            <option value="Butibori">Butibori</option>
            <option value="Hingna">Hingna</option>
        </select>
        <label for="group">Group</label>
        <select name='group'>
            <option value='finishedProduct'>Finished Products</option>
            <option value='scrapMaterial'>Scrap Material</option>
            <option value='rerollingMaterial'>Rerolling Material</option>
            <option value='coal'>Coal</option>
            <option value='machinery'>Machinery</option>
            <option value='freight'>Freight</option>
        </select>
        <label for="item">Item</label>
        <select name='item'>
            <option value='squareBar'>Square Bar</option>
            <option value='roundBar'>Round Bar</option>
            <option value='flatBar'>Flat Bar</option>
            <option value='angle'>Angle</option>
            <option value='gateChannel'>Gate Channel</option>
        </select>
        <label for="itemSpecifics">Item Specifics</label>
        <select name='sqaureBar'>
            <option value='6mmFixed'>6mm Fixed</option>
            <option value='6mmRandom'>6mm Random</option>
            <option value='8mmFixed'>8mm Fixed</option>
            <option value='8mmRandom'>8mm Random</option>
            <option value='10mmFixed'>10mm Fixed</option>
            <option value='10mmRandom'>10mm Random</option>
            <option value='12mmFixed'>12mm Fixed</option>
            <option value='12mmRandom'>12mm Random</option>
        </select>
        <input type="number" name="quantity" placeholder="Total Quantity">
        <input type="number" name="rate" placeholder="Rate per Ton">
        <input type="number" name="amount" placeholder="Total Amount">
        <input type="text" name="comments" placeholder="Comments">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <%- include("partials/footer"); -%>
```

Right now I don't get anything into the value field but I want the customer name that is produced in snake case. By the way, the MySQL database has a customers table with a few names in it.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just put both values in your map?

```
//App.js
const map = rows.map(name => {displayName: name.customerName, snakeCaseName: _.snakeCase(name.customerName)});
```

You could then omit one of the parameters to the render function:

```
//App.js
res.render("home.ejs", {
customerNames: map
});
```

And render it with:

```
<select>
<% customerNames.forEach((name) => { %>
<option value=<%= name.snakeCaseName %>><%= name.displayName %></option>
<% }) %>
</select>
```